# Angular 2 re-apply [ngStyle] after animation ends

Tags: angular, css-animations

I have a set of images, that I'm positioning absolutely next to each other. To do this, I have on each image element:

```
[ngStyle]="{
      'left': ((i % 5)*150) + 'px',
      'top': (Math.floor(i / 5)*150) + 'px'
    }"
```

where i is the index. When you click one of the images, it is brought to the center of the page. To do this, I then have the following animation states in the component:

```
state('visible', style({
    opacity: 1,
    transform: 'scale(1)',
    'z-index': 0,
    'box-shadow': 'none',
    'transform-origin': 'initial'
  })),
state('clicked',style({
    transform: 'scale(3)',
    'transform-origin': '0 0',
    top: '25px',
    left: '150px',
    opacity: 1,
    'z-index': 2,
    'box-shadow': '0 0 20px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)'
  })),
```

This works when I click on the image. However, when I click on the image again, I transition 'clicked'=>'visible'. Since the [ngStyle] was overriden by the 'clicked' styling, when it goes back to the 'visible' state, the left and top styling that [ngStyle] applied are gone, and every image just goes to the top left.

Things I've tried:

1) Variables in the animation -> not supported by angular

2) Intercepting the callback of the animation starting 'clicked'=>'visible' and re-adding in the top and left styling on the element => This only adds the styling back once the animation is over. So the image moves to the top left then jumps back into its spot (ew)

3) Not using position absolute for the default images => Then when I move the images to the middle of the page, every other element jumps up one which is bad.